# ORA-01873 when calculating the difference between two timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to produce the number of days between two timestamps, as a precise fractional number.
My code is producing `ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small`

This single line seems to be the culprit.
When I remove this one line, the query starts working again.

```
SELECT
...
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM 24*60*60*(ssts.TIMESTAMP - MAX(pssts.TIMESTAMP)))/(24*60*60) AS DAYS_SINCE_PREV_TIMESTAMP,
...
FROM ...
```

What is wrong with it?
It was working fine last week.

Comment: I see a downvote. I don't understand it. A note from the downvoter, explaining his or her objection to this question, would be helpful. (More helpful, perhaps, than the downvote itself.) For what it's worth, in my opinion the question makes perfect sense, and the OP has posted enough information to make it perfectly clear. Perhaps the confusion is in the mind of the downvoter, and there is in fact nothing wrong with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two timestamps will produce interval which is the day to second.

If you want the precise fractional number then you can achieve it using date datatype.

```
Select
...
cast(ssts.TIMESTAMP as date) - cast(MAX(pssts.TIMESTAMP) as date)
...
```

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=298e2c086d88b42a719e0df32a17f8d2) demo of difference in timestamp and dates.

Cheers!!

Comment: Difference between two timestamps is an interval, not another timestamp.

Comment: Yes, That was. Ohh, I typed it as a timestamp. Let me correct it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you multiply by 86,400 after you take the difference of time intervals, then extract DAY and then divide the result by 86,400. You talk about "a precise fractional number"; I don't see how your formula has that effect.

In any case, that is very likely the culprit, and I don't see an easy workaround. (Stating again, though, that I don't see how what you do there is helpful in any way.)

The difference between two timestamps is an interval day to second. The number of days can be a number up to nine digits long. This is fine for taking timestamp differences between pretty much any historical dates. However, when you multiply by 86,400, you end up with an interval that may be more than 10^9 days. Simple tests show that a difference between a timestamp in 2019 and one in 1990, multiplied by 86,400, is still within nine-digit days; but if you subtract a timestamp in 1980, you will get exactly the overflow violation you saw (the error about "leading precision of the interval is too small"). You can, of course, divide 10^9 by 86,400 to get the greatest number of days for which your query would work.

What changed from last week? Either the data in the table has changed, or - less likely, but possible - you already had a date in the 1980's in the data, and you were bumping right against the upper bound for where the formula would still work. Now it's a week later and perhaps that's the straw that broke the camel's back?

What is the value of `MAX(pssts.TIMESTAMP)`, by itself? This can easily show you if my explanation is correct.

Comment: All the timestamps are between December 5th 2019 and December 9th 2019, with no exceptions. This is so bizarre ... I've always been a Microsoft SQL Server guy, and Oracle's timestamp arithmetic makes no sense to me at all. I got the 86,400 idea from StackOverflow, because that was how people recommended calculating the number of days between two timestamps. Is there a better way, that doesn't encounter this potential problem?